# How can i make my own interface with methods from other class?

Tags: java, interface

I need to create an interface that will declare methods from File class + some of my methods.
How can i realize my interface, so all taken from File class methods would do the same they do in File class?
[my task](http://cs605624.vk.me/v605624202/42a4/HIrYsUnIfKc.jpg)
i dont know how to do it

Comment: You can't. You can however extend `File`.

Comment: `public myClass extends myBaseClass{
//TODO
}`

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted. I think this is a valid question.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're trying to achieve ? How do you intend to use that interface ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu see added task please

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your own interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void myMethod();
}
```

And then declare your own class extending `File` and implementing your interface:

```
public class MyFile extends File implements MyInterface {

    public MyFile(String pathname) {
        super(pathname);
        // Additional constructor code.
    }

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        // Overridden method from MyInterface.
        System.out.println("My method!");
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        // Overridden method from File.
        return "MyFileName";
    }
}
```

That way, you have a class acting like a `File` with additional methods from your custom interface, and you can override the methods you want from `File`.

Example of use:

```
MyInterface customFile = new MyFile("myFile.txt");
customFile.myMethod();
```

Comment: The question implies that the interface needs to declare all the public methods of the `File` class, so I guess you should enhance `MyInterface` accordingly.

Comment: will i be able to create objects based on Myinterface with this way?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu `File` has a large number of methods, so I honestly think extending from it and overriding the methods you want to act differently is better than populating an interface with **all** of `File`'s methods. `MyInterface` here is only for the additional behaviour that is not part of `File`.

Comment: @Cupuycblack Yes, totally. See the added example on my answer.

Comment: My wild guess (since the question hardly provides any hints) is that the interface is supposed to be used like: `MyInterface ref = ...; ref.getAbsoluteFile(); ref.toURL(); ref.myMethod(); ...`. But I may be wrong; anyway, you have my upvote.

Comment: see added task to my question